# Android switch off SwitchPreference programmatically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

Is there a way to switch off a SwitchPreference programmatically? I tried using `setEnabled(false)` but that just disables the SwitchPreference, but the switch stays in the on position.

Is there a method to disable the switch programmatically so it goes back to the off position?

Answer (score 4):

setEnabled as you say is to enable/disable the actual switch.

To turn it on/off programmatically try setChecked(true) / setChecked(false): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#setChecked(boolean)